# Why does the '.ics/vcs' file cannot open with office365, if TZID parameter present

Tags: timezone, office365, icalendar

In my application I am sending mail to various users.The mail is attached with an .ics file. But when the user tries to open the file in **Office365** an error pop ups which says

**'The .ICS attachment can't be viewed because the format is not supported'**.

Please see below the .ics file I have used

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170322T064351Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/Denver:20170323T110000
DTEND;TZID=America/Denver:20170323T113000
SUMMARY:WAND: Test Summary
TZID:America/Denver
LOCATION:
UID:20170322T064351Z-1@fe80:0:0:0:0:100:7f:fffe%12
DESCRIPTION:Candidate Name: Test User\nContact Phone Number: 1256355
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The issue occurs when I have added the Timezone parameter recently.But this will work if I remove the Timezone parameter.

That is, if I replace

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/Denver:20170323T110000
DTEND;TZID=America/Denver:20170323T113000
```

with the below one

```
DTSTART:20170323T110000
DTEND:20170323T113000
```

the issue does not occur. But I need to add timezone.

Any additional elements need to add for the timezone parameter?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ics stream shown in your example seems to be truncated (missing at least the BEGIN:VCALENDAR) but assuming it is there in your actual ics, you are also supposed to include a VTIMEZONE component (before the BEGIN:VEVENT) that corresponds to the TZID=America/Denver used in your DTSTART/DTEND.

See for example the second example at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-4